# Scala parsing recursive bracket tree

Tags: scala, parsing, recursion, tree

I am new to Scala and I am trying to apply it in a recursive structure that can be seen as a tree. The main problem is that is not a binary tree. The grammar looks like this:

```
<Tree> := <Node> {"[" {<Tree>}+ "]"}?
```

Where Node is a literal. The problem is that I don't know how to make this recursive context free grammar with the Scala combinator parsers, I don't even know if this is possible. Basically, it is optional to have child Trees, but there is no limit in how many child subtrees a tree can have.

I look in stackoverflow but didn't find anything about a Tree structure like this. The idea is to parse the string to get a data structure representing it (with the attributes Node and a list of the childs)

Comment: That should be pretty easy to encode with Scala's combinator parsers. You should go read up on it. [There's a whole chapter on it in the *Programming in Scala* book.](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html) That online version of the book is the 1st edition, but I don't think the combinator parsing library has changed significantly since then. You'll probably just have to add some imports to enable language features.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of the online version of that book.